# Rails 7: How to encrypt a Date attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, encryption

Using Rails 7's application-level encryption feature, `String` attributes (such as `Author.email` in the below example) can be encrypted by a simple declaration such as:

```
class Author < ApplicationRecord
  encrypts :email, deterministic: true
end
```

How does one encrypt a `Date` attribute such as `Author.dateofbirth` (or a `Datetime` attribute)?

Comment: I'm guessing the solution would be to store the date in a text type column (varchar) as an encrypted ISO8601 timestamp and then maybe handle serialization with a custom type created with the [ActiveModel::Type](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/Type.html) API. I can see some serious downsides to this though as you won't be able to use the column in queries.

Comment: @max - I can confirm: a `Date` must be stored as a `String` (but serialization happens automatically). And thus, queries can only happen as `String` queries, i.e.: `Author.where(dateofbirth: "2000-12-30").first`, never as `Date` queries.